# Python - Additional "members" appended to JSON object when passing it to function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, typeerror

I have the following JSON object located in its own file called build.json:

```
{
    "name": "utils",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "includes": [],
    "libraries": [],
    "testLibraries": []
}
```

I obtain this object in my Python program using the following method:

```
def getPackage(packageName):
    jsonFilePath = os.path.join(SRCDIR, packageName, "build.json")
    packageJson = None
    try:
        with open(jsonFilePath, "r") as jsonFile:
            packageJson = json.load(jsonFile)
    except:
        return None
    return packageJson
```

I verify that the JSON object for the current package (which is one of many packages I am iterating over) did not come back None in the following method. Note that I am temporarily printing out the keys of the dictionary:

```
def compileAllPackages():
    global COMPILED_PACKAGES

    for packageName in os.listdir(SRCDIR):
        package = getPackage(packageName)
        if package == None:
            continue

        # TEMP ==============
        for i in package:
            print(i)
        # ===================

        compiledSuccessfully = compilePackage(package)
        if not compiledSuccessfully:
            return False
    return True
```

Lastly, I am currently also printing out the keys of the dictionary once it is received in the compilePackage function:

```
def compilePackage(package):
    global COMPILED_PACKAGES, INCLUDE_TESTS

    # TEMP ==============
    for i in package:
        print(i)
    # ===================        

    ...
```

Output from compileAllPackages function:

```
name
version
includes
libraries
testLibraries
```

Output from compilePackage function:

```
name
version
includes
libraries
testLibraries
u
t
i
l
s
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what is happening to my dictionary during that function call??? Please note that the build.json file is located within a directory named "utils".

**Edit:**
The Python script is located separate from the build.json file and works on absolute paths. It should also be noted that after getting that strange output, I also get the following exception when trying to access a valid key later (it seems to think the dictionary is a string?...):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nate/bin/BuildTool/unix/build.py", line 493, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/nate/bin/BuildTool/unix/build.py", line 481, in main
    compiledSuccessfully = compileAllPackages()
  File "/Users/nate/bin/BuildTool/unix/build.py", line 263, in compileAllPackages
    compiledSuccessfully = compilePackage(package)
  File "/Users/nate/bin/BuildTool/unix/build.py", line 287, in compilePackage
    compiledSuccessfully = compilePackage(include)
  File "/Users/nate/bin/BuildTool/unix/build.py", line 279, in compilePackage
    includes = getPackageIncludes(package)
  File "/Users/nate/bin/BuildTool/unix/build.py", line 194, in getPackageIncludes
    includes = [package["name"]]    # A package always includes itself
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**Edit: If I change the parameter name to something other than 'package', I no longer get that weird output or an exception later on. This is not necessarily a fix, however, as I do not know what could be wrong with the name 'package'. There are no globals named as such either.**

Comment: I'm with @benediktwerner. I don't think the 'utils' part comes from anywhere in this code. Try searching for all other points in your code where you print and see if it might be coming from one of them. Better yet, print something before and after the for loops like say `########` so you can properly demarcate where that part's output starts and ends.

Comment: @Karuhanga I can comment out all of my printouts such that I get no output except for the exception. Then if I only allow that one print loop in the compilePackage function, the result is as seen above. I don't believe there is anything in the print buffer either that wasn't flushed before-hand.

Comment: Have you tried just `print(package)` and see what you got?

Comment: @Idlehands yes. If I replace each looping print with print(package) above, from compileAllPackages, I get: 
`{'name': 'utils', 'version': '1.0.0', 'includes': [], 'libraries': [], 'testLibraries': []}`

and from compilePackage, I get (still with that weird utils string tacked onto the end):
`{'name': 'utils', 'version': '1.0.0', 'includes': [], 'libraries': [], 'testLibraries': []}
utils`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being very stupid. compilePackage() has the possibility of being called recursively, due to any dependencies the package may rely on. In recursive calls to the function, I was passing a string to the function rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

I tried your code and the result is like this

Output from compileAllPackages function:

```
name
version
includes
libraries
testLibraries
```

Output from compilePackage function:

```
name
version
includes
libraries
testLibraries
```

My directory structure is like this

```
├── test.py
└── tt
    └── cc
        └── utils
            └── build.json
```

I think your code is correct, it should be that the path parameter you passed is incorrect.

Comment: `it should be that the path parameter you passed is incorrect`. This does not explain why you would have different output for identical pieces of code.

Comment: This is not an answer and must be posted as a comment.